# Textures will not appear

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to add textures to an object through the materials/textures panels, but no matter what I do, it won't work.

Render viewport mode just gives me black. Texture and material viewport modes give the color of the material but not the texture. Cycles render, blender game, blender render, all useless.

Maximum Draw Type is already set to "textured" and nodes don't work. I've been searching for an answer for hours and nothing's worked.

EDIT: There is no option to add an "image texture" anywhere in the materials tab. Not that it matters, because even the pre-loaded textures don't appear.

Here is the file:

[image]

EDIT EDIT: I also do not get an option to "unwrap" and even before that, I get nothing but a black texture.

[image]

EDIT EDIT EDIT: I get the brick texture on the body but not the hair. Using an image also gets just plain gray, not the image as a texture. And when I switch to Blender Render it turns bright orange.

Comment: hard to tell, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Uploaded [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5236" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5236/)

Comment: You have to switch to material shading to view procedural textures and to textured shading to view the **actively selected** texture node. The answer of the duplicate question can be reproduced with your file. [Image (click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bibb.gif)

Comment: No it can't. I just get a blank black texture